# What's the difference between these two conditions?

Tags: c++

The expression `j > 0 && a[j - 1] > value_to_insert` appears in the definition of the `sort_ints` function. Why would it not be acceptable to rewrite this as `a[j-1] > value_to_insert && j > 0`? I tried putting the condition the other way around and it gave me the same output as the original.

Here's the function definition:

```
void sort_ints(int *a, int n)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int value_to_insert;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        value_to_insert = a[i];

        /* Shift values greater than value_to_insert. */
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && a[j - 1] > value_to_insert) {
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        a[j] = value_to_insert;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Giving the same output" is not the same as "is a correct program", unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Because due to the [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) property of the `&&` operator, the modified code (your "working" version, that doesn't really work) would most likely invoke undefined behavior by accessing the -1th element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined behaviour to evaluate `a[-1]`. Since the logical-AND operator `&&` has short-circuited semantics, `a[j - 1]` is never evaluated if `j == 0` in the original code.

Comment: It's not necessarily undefined behavior to evaluate `a[-1]`, since `a` may point to an element other than the 1st of an array.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That's absolutely true, but since this is a sorting function, it is *very likely* to have UB.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I should have said "it is *generally* UB"... meh, you got to pick your battles.